# SQLite update item values

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In update method contentvalues must store values only for field that I want to change or for every field?

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("field1", new_value);
    db.update(table, contentValues, "serial code="+serial_code,null);
```

or

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("field1", new_value);
    contentValues.put("field2", value2);
    contentValues.put("field3", value3);
    ...
    contentValues.put("lastfield", value99);
    db.update(table, contentValues, "serial code="+serial_code,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add only those columns value which you want to update no need to pass values for all columns  for any table in SQLite Content Values.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the column values which have changed, ,find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))